# Activity Scheduling algorithm design to maximize the number of activities

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy

I am working on an activity scheduling algorithm. Let's say there are N number of activities. Each activity can only be done within the specified timings (e.g. 8am-5pm) and there is time duration it takes to complete the activity (e.g. 2 hours). I want to finish as many activities I can in a day with start and end time. E.g.

1. Activity 1 (8am-5pm) takes 2 hours
2. Activity 2 (7am- 11am) takes 1.5 hours
3. Activity 3 (11am-3pm) takes 1 hours
4. Activity 4 (1pm-3:30pm) takes 1.5 hours
5. Activity 5 (6am-8pm) takes 3 hours
6. Activity 6 (11am-6pm) takes 2 hours
7. Activity 7 (2pm-5pm) takes 1 hours
8. Activity 8 (7pm-12pm) takes 1 hours

I want to do as many activities as possible from 8am-8pm. I looked at [Greedy Activity Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem) algorithm but my case is a bit different than this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried this logic:

```
Activity[] possibleActivities; // this has all the activities, Activity object has startTime, endTime and duration.
int dayStartTime= 8; //8am
int dayEndTime= 18; //6pm
Arrays.sort(possibleActivities); // sort the activities based on the startTime
int hours=dayStartTime;
List<Activity> dailyActitiy=new ArrayList<>();
for(Activity activity: possibleActivities){
    if(activity.startTime<=hours && hours<dayEndTime){
        dailyActitiy.add(activity);
        hours+=dailyActitiy.duration;
    }

 }
 return dailyActitiy;
```

Comment: Thanks @m69, added my code. Not sure if this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the scheduling literature, this would be termed a single-machine scheduling problem with variable processing times, release dates, and due dates. This variant is NP-hard (if I'm reading the classic literature correctly), so I recommend [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) via an off-the-shelf solver.

One formulation is to make a 0-1 variable for all activity-time slot pairs (e.g., Activity 2, which is 1.5 hours between 7am and 11am gets variables x(2,7am-8:30am), x(2,7:30am-9am), x(2,8am-9:30am), x(2,8:30am-10am), x(2,9am-10:30am), x(2,9:30am-11am)) indicating whether the activity should be done in the time slot. The objective is to maximize the sum of all of these variables. There are two types of constraints: for each activity, the sum of its variables should be at most one, so that each activity is scheduled at most once; for each unit of time (half hours in the example), the sum of all variables containing that unit should be at most one, so each moment has at most one scheduled activity.

Comment: Hello David, can you point to me an off-the-shelf solver. The only one I could find were paid, do you know if there is any open-source library I could use?

Comment: @SameerMalhotra See also http://www.gurobi.com/resources/switching-to-gurobi/open-source-solvers